# Invitation to all users link in rails link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined a function which sends email to 200 parents when we click on send invitation email. The issue I am facing is when I click on send invitation email i get a message "Invitation email have already been sent to all". But there are many parents to whom email has not been sent.

parents_controller.rb

```
def send_email_to_everyone
    @parents = Parent.where(invitation_email_sent: false, admin: false, email: !nil).limit(200)
    # puts @parents.length
    if @parents.length > 0
        @parents.each do |parent|
            parent.create_reset_digest
            ParentMailer.invitation_confirmation(parent).deliver
            parent.update_attributes(invitation_email_sent: true)
        end
          flash[:success] = "Invitation email has been sent to all."
          redirect_to main_admin_path
        else
          flash[:success] = "Invitation email have already been sent to all"
          redirect_to main_admin_path           
        end
    end
```

main_admin.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Send Invitation Email", send_email_to_everyone_path, class: "btn btn-info btn-2x" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you select your parents, you write `email: !nil`.
In rails `!nil` is `true`.
So you are looking for parents whose email is the value `true`. You should write :

```
    @parents = Parent.where(invitation_email_sent: false, admin: false).where.not(email: nil).limit(200)
```

I replaced
`.where(email: !nil)` with `.where.not(email: nil)`

Comment: @parents = Parent.where(invitation_email_sent: false, admin: false, not(email: nil)).limit(200) This is how I should write it?

Comment: No, actually, the syntax in your comment is not correct, if you use not like this, it would try to call the not method (probably in the controller class of the file), what you want is to call a not method of active record, the library provided by rails to query databases. So you need to chain 2 wheres like I wrote in my answer, and use the where.not method provided by active record : https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot

Comment: 501 Recipient syntax error I get if I try the way you suggested

Comment: I think it's another issue, you should look at the backtrace of the error, it's probably an error when you're trying to send the email